# showing listview data in html5 from database using javascript and json

Tags: javascript, json, html, listview

Showing listview data in html5 from database using java script and json. Click listview is Show detail. I can make show listview but can't show detail. The changing page. Listview 1 page, Detail 1 page.

This is code run successful. but can't show detail.

```js
   $(function() {

   var people = [];
   var json = "your url";       
 
   $.getJSON(json, function(json1) {
       $.each(json1, function(key, data) {       
     
      $('#myUL').append('<li data-id="' + data.VendorCode + '"><a href="#"><img src="http://Order%20Custumer/images/'+data.VendorCode+'.png"/><h3 style="color:#FFCC00">' + data.LocalDesc + '</h3><p style="color:#FF9">' + data.EngDesc + '</p></a></li>');
        });
  
        $('#myUL').listview('refresh');    
   });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!--
 Intensify by TEMPLATED
 templated.co @templatedco
 Released for free under the Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 license (templated.co/license)
-->
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Salad Lovers</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
</head>    
  
<body>
<ul id="myUL" data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you included jquery file in your html page?

Comment: $("#myUL").on("click",function(){
//write your code here
});

Answer (score 0):

Include Jquery Library in your HTML file before  tag and try running it.

```
<script
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

your HTML File seems to be:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!--
    Intensify by TEMPLATED
    templated.co @templatedco
    Released for free under the Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 license (templated.co/license)
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Salad Lovers</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
</head>



<body>
<ul id="myUL" data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
</ul>
<script
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How click listview is Show detail?

Comment: @AumeBunKumruck 
is above answer resolved your problem ? if yes then please accept that answer. to click on list item,you can write: 
$("#myUL").on("click",function(){ //write your code here });

Comment: @AumeBunKumruck ??